# How to design an algorithm that initializes once every 20 times it's called?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have designed a function that is a called when an event happens. However, I need this function to calculate the average of the prices given to it up until 20 numbers, and when it's less than 20 numbers do nothing, and when it calculates the 20 numbers then reset the list to zero. But I can't do this.

The logic for this is that, when the program starts (is initialized) it calls this function, and for any price change event this function is called, however, based on the first 20 price change the program decides to do something, and then it is not called until something bad happens to the program. However, next time the program is restarted, it still has the previous values for svm20average and just calculates the last price and the 19 prices from days ago, when the program was initialized.

```
svm20average = []
def order_function(price_x, price_y):
    price_x = price_x
    price_y = price_y
    svm20average.append(price_x)
    if len(svm20average) < 20:
        print 'Calculating \n'
    elif len(svm20average) >= 20:
        t = []
        for i in range(len(svm20average)):
            t.append(svm20average[i]-svm20average[0])
            print '.'
        xt = np.asarray(t)
        yt = np.average(xt)
        order_executer(yt, price_x, price_y)
    svm20average = []
```

This is the error:

```
svm20average.append(price_x)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'svm20average' referenced before assignment
```

update: I have this function being called from a main program that never exists. That's the problem. I have a main function that connects to a server and fetches a line, from server for ever. Every time a line is fetched, this algorithm is called, however, the first time that this algorithm is called, it calculates the first 20 averages and pass it along to another function order_executer. Then this function is not called unless some specific line is fetched again, maybe days later. This time this algorithm is called again, however, 19 of numbers are from before and only the last price is from the last call.

update 2: I tried, del svm20average[:] and del svm20average[:-20], they don't work, since it says svm20average is unresolved, when put out of the loop and when put inside it causes the problem. please read the comments for more details.

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to design an algorithm that initializes `every time` it's called?

Comment: Yes. Something along that line. That would be easier to design something that initializes every time it's called, but a bit more tricky to design something that initializes once every 20 times it's called.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the function to remember its state, even after the program exits and is later restarted?

Comment: No, the program never exists. That's the problem. I have a main function that connects to a server and fetches a line, from server for ever. Every time a line is fetched, this algorithm is called, however, the first time that this algorithm is called, it calculates the first 20 averages and pass it along to another function order_executer. Then this function is not called unless some specific line is fetched again, maybe days later. This time this algorithm is called again, however, 19 of numbers are from before and only the last price is from the last call.

Comment: Then you've lost me. The first time this function is called all it does is print "Calculating" and immediately return. I don't understand "*the first time that this algorithm is called, it calculates the first 20 averages and pass it along to another function*". As far as I can tell, it doesn't call `order_execute` until the **20th** time it is called.

Comment: yes, it is called consecutively from the main program. It get the price from the main program, and after 20 times that it's called, it get's out of the "calculating", and calculates the average, and pass it along to the order_execute but the next time it's called, it doesn't wait for it to be called 20 times (which is needed to get the latest updated twenty prices and that's what I want the algorithm to do) but alas it goes and acts on the last updated number and 19 numbers from the first twenty times it was called.

Comment: the trick is to somehow, set the svm20average = [] after it's twenty times is calculated, so set the stage for the next step. but the last line arise an error in python.

Comment: So basically, there's a buffer of prices somewhere, of fixed maximum size N, and you don't want to start calculating until size N is reached, and thereafter you want to recalculate every time a new value is added to the buffer?

Comment: True, this is the problem. The buffer actually is svm20average, because it keeps the data in it, forever, as long as the main program is running, but I want  svm20average to be set to nothing after execution of the algorithm (when it has calculated the average of twenty prices)

Comment: Update the question to a self-contained problem statement and remove the comments, instead of adding an exhortation to read the comments for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code gives a `local variable referenced before assignment` error for `svm20average`. This means that you are referencing a variable declared outside your function, meaning that it does not exist within the scope of `order_function`. To allow your code to run as is, it would have to pass in this array as input so that the function can access it, like so:

```
def order_function(price_x, price_y, array):
    price_x = price_x
    price_y = price_y
    array.append(price_x)
    # etc
```

And you would call it like:

```
svm20average = []
order_function(pricex, pricey, svm20average)
```

In addition, you could clear the data in svm20average by doing `del svm20average[:]`.

Comment: please read my question more carefully. I don't see how this might work.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking. If I can't figure it out in a few minutes, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Okay, are you trying to only run calculations on 'svm20average' when it has 20+ items in it, and then trying to clear it, and are having trouble doing this?

Comment: I tried, del svm20average[:] and del svm20average[:-20], they don't work, since it says svm20average is unresolved, when put out of the loop and when put inside it causes the problem.

Comment: That's pretty important info. Could you please update your question with this?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error you are actually getting from python into your question? Anything I get from trying to run your code could be different from what you are actually having trouble with.

Comment: `svm20average.append(pricex)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'svm20average' referenced before assignment`